# Change the size of the image itself in R

Tags: r

I use "plot" function in R to draw a picture.I want to change the size of the image itself instead of the drawing area,then I will save it to show elsewhere.

I have tried to use the following code.

```
par(cex = 2) # change the size of the content in the image not itself
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3),type = "p")
```

But it can only change the size of the content in the image not itself.I hope to get your help.

Comment: Write the output using one of the many functions (e.g. `?pdf`). Use arguments `width` and `height` to adjust image size.

Comment: I have used "png" function,but it cannot work.

Comment: The official document describe that "
the width and height of the graphics region in inches. The default values are 7."

Comment: Have you tried `png("try.png",1280,720);plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3),type = "p");dev.off()`?

Comment: I have tried,the arguments width and height are used to set the size of graphics region instead of graphics itself.You can see the above comment.

Comment: We don't know what code you've used that didn't work and can't help figure out why it didn't work unless we can see it in your question. Feel free to [edit] with the code you've used to save.

Comment: Are you read my question carefully?I have shown the code that I tried.

Comment: Yes I am. You said you're going to save the image, and in comments you mention using `png` to save the image, but it doesn't work. How exactly it didn't work is unclear, and that code isn't here in order to help debug it.

Comment: he is using the "graphics" package. the par() function in his first line is used to set the many of the plots parameters. Instead of the "cex" parameter, he needs to use the "pin" parameter as explained in the package documentation for the par() function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the documentation for the par() function in the graphics package lists all the parameters you can set for the plot.

The parameter you want is "pin" (plot dimensions (width, height) in inches)

so then

```
par(pin = c(5,3))
```

sets plot width to five inches, height to 3 inches.

The parameter "cex" is defined as a numerical value giving the amount by which plotting text and symbols should be magnified relative to the default.

Comment: It would help if down-voter explained the down vote so that Bruce can learn and/or improve his answer.